# Change a text element to image in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How can I change the text "Previous" to an image element?

```
href:"#",title:"Previous",text:"Previous"}).appendTo(n);
```

Basically it is a image slider and these are the navigation text elements "Previous" and "Next"

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/2502jvn.png]

Comment: @User What is that?  It sort of looks like JavaScript, but it obviously got mangled somewhere along the line – the parentheses aren't even balanced.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing on what got lost in the copying. Here's what I think you need:

```
$('<a>', {  href: "#",
            title: "Previous"
            html: '<img alt="Previous", src="/images/previous.jpg">' }).appendTo(n);
```